# Overriding keyDown causes issues to a NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my NSTableView subclass MyTableView I've overwritten

```
- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)event {

    if ( [event keyCode] == 51 || [event keyCode] == 117 ) {
        [super keyDown:event];
        return;
    }

}
```

51 is the code for the delete button. I'm expecting the table view to delete the selected item as before the subclassing.

The event is correctly caught and the keyDown method of the superclass is invoked. However, the item is not deleted anymore. Why ?

Thanks

Comment: 2 questions: what are you trying to do?  and are you catching keyUp as well as keyDown?

Comment: @gaige 1.I need to invoke a method when delete button is pressed. 2 No, should I ? By default the items are already deleted when the key is down.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do.  Why are you catching keydown here if items are already deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommend you override keyDown: in your window class.

```
-(void) keyDown: (NSEvent *) event
{
    NSString *chars = [event characters];
    unichar character = [chars characterAtIndex: 0];
    if (character == NSDeleteCharacter || character == NSBackspaceCharacter) 
    {
        NSTableView* view = (NSTableView*)[self firstResponder];
        if(view == theTableView)
        {
        // do something to delete the item from your data model and reload the tableview
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying just to invoke a specific method when the Delete key is pressed, I'd suggest overriding the `-deleteBackward:` method (part of `NSResponder`), because it isolates this interception more specifically.   It also manages the problem of remapped keyboards, macros, etc.

There's also `-deleteForward` for the delete key instead of the backspace key.

```
-(void)deleteBackward:(id)sender
{
     // do my override here
     // do this only if super implements deleteBackward:
     [super deleteBackward: sender]
}
```